# edit the width, height of Jquery ui combobox

Tags: jquery, css

I tried to edit the size of Jquery ui combobox. I changed the width and height but nothing change.

How to change or edit the width and height?

I like just like this small http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('.ui-autocomplete-input').css('width','300px')
$('.ui-autocomplete-input').css('height','300px')
```

You can also do that in open event of autocomplete:

```
$('.ui-autocomplete-input').autocomplete({  
source: mysource,  
appendTo: '#div',  
open: function() { $('#div .ui-menu').width(300);$('#div .ui-menu').height(500) }  
});
```

Comment: where I should place that?

Comment: where are you setting the autocomplete for combobox.